# Methods required in only 2 classes out of 20 that implement an interface

Tags: android, interface, scene, game-loop, implements

**Background**

In my app (game) - I have a *scene manager* to handle the different levels.  So I have:

*Interface code*

```
//Interface to allow switching scenes (works in conjunction with SceneManager class)
//Handles rendering, logic updating (on the GL rendering thread) and user input (on the main UI thread)

public interface Scene  {

void render();
void updateLogic();
boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);

}
```

*SceneManager class*

```
//Scene Manager class used in conjunction with the Scene interface.  This allows for querying of the current
//scene & changing the scene using the current instance of the manager.

public class SceneManager {

private static SceneManager Instance = new SceneManager();

private Scene currentScene;

public static SceneManager getInstance(){

    return Instance;

}

public Scene getCurrentScene(){

    return currentScene;

}

public void setCurrentScene(Scene scene){

    currentScene = scene;

}

}
```

So, from my Game-loop I can do something like this:

```
SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().updateLogic();
SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().render();
```

I can easily change my level by holding a simple int value and running the corresponding code through a switch statement.

```
switch (level){

case 1:{SceneManager.getInstance().setCurrentScene(r.level1);break


}
```

**The problem**

This works great but in a few of my levels (2 out of 20) I have a need to run a specific method, but I don't want to have to implement it in 18 levels in which it isn't required (by way of stub methods).

The other option I have is to call a switch statement on the level value while the loop is running so....

*Pseudo code*

```
If (level==5)

  callCode(5,0);

else if (level==10)

 {callCode (10,4);}
```

(Where levels 5 and 10 are the levels requiring this piece of code)

....but I would rather put the required method in it's corresponding level class and just call the method from the current scene as I'm not sure about using a switch (or for method) for this while the game loop itself is running flat-out - (IE, most of my switch statements come at cut scenes at the end of a level when performance isn't really an issue).  Something like this:

I would much rather just do something like this:

```
SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().callCode();
```

Where the callCode method would be specific to whatever values were needed in the levels (or indeed, could simply then in turn, call a main method of common code but with differing values).

Hope I'm making sense.

Any pointers would be appreciated

**Edit**

Attempting to create a 2nd interface as such:

```
public interface Scene2 extends Scene {

    void callCode();

}
```

(Scene remains as above)

Then, in my class (for example say level10)

```
public class Level10 implements Scene2 {

    @Override
    public void render(){

        //Rendering code goes here
        mainGame.Drawsprites();  //As an example.  MainGame implements Scene and contains all my game code.  I can simply call the various methods from any of my level classes therefore I don't duplicate tons of code

    }

     @Override
    public void updateLogic(){

        //Game updates goes here (Similar to above)

    }

    @Override
    public void callCode(){

        //Level specific code here

    }
```

from my mainGame class:

```
    public void doSomething(){

        SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().callCode;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this specific method a member of the `Scene` class, or is it a member of the `SceneManager` class?

Comment: Make a separate interface which has the required methods

Comment: Put it in a superclass or change the interface.

Comment: if the methods are specific to the scene, can you not just call them from the scene's implementation of updateLogic()?

Comment: Localize the `Scene` specific code to the `Scene`. I would propose using an `AbstractScene` where you could put your stub-do-nothing method, and provide a do-nothing implementation of `callCode`. From there you could override this method in your different levels. This way you could allways call `callCode`. This way your `callCode` implementation is localized to your scenes, and abstracted away from the general gameloop.

Comment: Or create a subtype for the special cases and implement a visitor pattern to do away with the switch construct.

Comment: My thoughts as extending both the questions from @Rob Garwood and atomman  is : Does the logic in callCode somewhat apply to general aspects of a scene? What I am missing are lifecycle - callbacks on your scene just like onCreate, onRendered, onUpdated . This would give you the most flexible approach imho because you could implement your logic in eventlisteners to this callbacks as well as implementing the execution of specific level logic directly in this methods.

Comment: To extend it further: also onBeforeUpdate onAfterUpdate is possible, of course leaving you with a fine - grained control over when additional code should be executed

Comment: I will post it as a proposal answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Interface `Scene`:

```
public interface Scene  {

void render();
void updateLogic();
boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);

}
```

You could define another Interface, something like:

```
    public interface Scene2 extends Scene {

    void callCode();

}
```

then in your mainGame class you can do:

```
public void doSomething(){

    Object currentScene = SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene();
    if(currentScene instanceof Scene){
        ((Scene)currentScene).render();
        ((Scene)currentScene).updateLogic();
    }

    if(currentScene instanceof Scene2){
        ((Scene2)currentScene).allCode();

    }

}
```

Comment: problem is how would this integrate into my SceneManager? (See my reply to Jeroen's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You should define an extra layer that extends your interface. Your 2 separate scenes can then implements this interface and still be called with the more general interface.

This is a sample implementation:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeInterface obj1 = new SomeClass2();
        obj1.method1();
        obj1.method2();
        SomeSubInterface obj2 = new SomeClass2();
        obj2.method1();
        obj2.method2();
        obj2.method3();
    }
}

interface SomeInterface {
    void method1();
    void method2();
}

interface SomeSubInterface extends SomeInterface {
    void method3();
}

class SomeClass1 implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

class SomeClass2 implements SomeSubInterface {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
    @Override
    public void method3() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: I have typtually attempted something like this already @JeroenVannevel but I can't seem to get it to work because my SceneManager class is working with only one Scene type (Scene in my case) so if I create another interface - say Scene2 and make my level class implement Scene2 rather than Scene, when I try to call the callCode(); method (which is in my level class) by doing this: SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().callCode(); it won't do it because the SceneManager is expecting a class which implements Scene and not Scene2 - how do I get around this?  thanks

Comment: You have to make your one interface extend the other one. `interface Scene2 extends Scene`.

Comment: Yeah @JeroenVannevel, Scene2 does indeed extend Scene1.  I'm getting the error: callCode cannot be resolved or is not a field.  It gives me 2 quick fixes which are to either (1) Create field 'callCode' in type 'Scene' or (2) create constant 'callCode' in type 'Scene'

Comment: Can you update your post to show some relevant code? Show the 2 interface definitions, the class declaration and the calling code. Don't forget to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example showcasing the solution I proposed in the comment above. As mentioned there it achieves to things, localization of scene specific code and it removes the complexity from the general gameloop.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scene scene1 = new NormalScene();
        Scene scene2 = new SpecialScene();

        scene1.initialize();    //Does nothing
        scene2.initialize();    //Print hello world
    }
}
abstract class Scene {
    abstract void render();
    abstract void updateLogic();
    abstract boolean onTouchEvent();
    void initialize() {

    }
}
class NormalScene extends Scene {
    @Override
    void render() {
    }
    @Override
    void updateLogic() {
    }
    @Override
    boolean onTouchEvent() {
        return true;
    }
}
class SpecialScene extends Scene {
    @Override
    void render() {
    }
    @Override
    void updateLogic() {
    }
    @Override
    boolean onTouchEvent() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my Comment, I would love an approach as the following as it perfectly fits into Android's Design and giving you the most flexibility imho:

```
public interface Scene  {

void render();
void updateLogic();
boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);

/** additional lifecycle callbacks **/
void onBeforeRender();
void onAfterRender();
void onBeforeUpdateLogic();
void onAfterUpdateLogic();
/** though the naming updateLogic associated that it is not a typicall lifecycle related method **/
}
```

And in your class of course the setters and getters for the eventlisteners to attach to the lifecycle events.

Comment: But remember the following collisions using lifecycle - callbacks: Whenever they are fully android conform, a class maybe restricted to rather implemting one of those. E.g. public interface Scene {protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) ...

Comment: and SceneActivity extends Activity implements Scene  /** ups **/

Comment: Thanks @Peter, if I understand correctly, you mean simply add the before/after methods (or indeed, say an exraCode(); method) & simply use this method when required.  Therefore these methods could perform different function depending on the needs of the specific scene?  I like this as it's I similar what I was doing originally, and therefore very simple, the main difference being that I was actually going to name my method specifically and have it contain specific code).  Disadvantage being that I still need to add stubs to the other 18 classes. Did I understand you correctly?  Thanks :-)

Comment: Yes. You would have to implement the lifecycle support both for the class handling it (mainly your Scenemanager) as well as providing a default implementation in your base class.

Comment: so while this may not be a general best solution to the problem described I think it fits into your concept because Scenes usually have some sort of common lifecycle events.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I may use this method, I do wonder however, if there is any way to do what I'm asking without having to add stubs to the remaining 18 classes? Let's say I add a method called extraCode(); to 2 of my 20 level classes and stubbs in the remaining 18, then put my extra code there...now I realise that I need another method.  I would need to create another method and add more stubs. The code that I need to run has to be run within my logic update - not before or after it.  Cheers!

Comment: Ups, now I got you: All your Scenes don't extend a common base class? Puh, I would consider this a wrong design. See, implementing interfaces has much more of the "a class supports a given concept" aspect as the opposite to a common base class which states that an object is a specialization or generalization of another.

Comment: So best choice really is to extract or implement a common super class. Still I would have this super class implement the lifecycle - callbacks mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Could I ask you to edit your answer to give me an example of what you mean please?  My Scenes don't extend a superclass, rather I pass in a common class to all my Level Scenes via the constructor (the common class being MainGame).  Maybe  bad design yeah.  MainGame is also a Scene and is home to the bulk of the code that my Level Scenes call (So, MainGame contains say a doSomething(); method), it is passed into Level1 and Level1 calls it in the form of MainGame.doSomething(); so it doesn't have to be duplicated in all 20 level Scenes. An edit would really be appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Distilled from the other answers and based on your comments: what I think you really want to do to minimize the `Scene` interface as much as possible is to add the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) into your code (it's a double dispatch design pattern). Basically for you it would mean something like (I assume here that level 2 and 4 are the level classes you want to call special methods in):

```
interface LevelVisitor {
    void visit(Level2 level);

    void visit(Level4 level);
}

interface Scene {
    // Other methods stay the same as you have

    accept(LevelVisitor visitor);
}
```

Your different levels now have a `accept` method (leave it empty in the classes you do not need it in 18/20 classes), above I made the `LevelVisitor` receive the concrete `class` implementations for your `Level2` and `Level4` classes (the two specific levels).

Let `MainGame` class implement `LevelVisitor` interface which means that there are now two new methods in the MainGame class, those receiving concrete `Level2` and `Level4` class implementations. So now from `MainGame` you call (`MainGame/this` gets dispatched to levels wanting it, `MainGame` is the visitor):

```
SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().accept(this);
```

and also you have the visit methods in `MainGame`

```
public void visit(Level2 level) {
    level.specificMethodInLevel2();
}

public void visit(Level4 level) {
    level.specificMethodInLevel4();
}
```

and in `Level2` and `Level4` classes you have the accept method with non empty implementation, like this in `Level2` (`Level2/this` gets dispatched to visit method of `MainGame`):

```
public void accept(LevelVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
}
```

**Now you could add specific methods (e.g. `specificMethodInLevel2()`) to both `Level2` and `Level4` concrete classes which are not seen from the other levels, and call them from the visit methods of your `MainGame` class. Also due the dispatching nature of visitor pattern you end up without the switch cases (all ''special'' levels are now handled in separate methods).**

Comment: @Zippy I know you said you did not want to stub but I see no way out from it here, what you gain by doing the above though is that you can call specific level `class` methods that are not part of the interface, which is what I think you really wanted to begin with. Also due the dispatching nature of `visitor` pattern you end up without the switch cases.

Comment: @Zippy what have you done so far? Did you solve your problem? One more idea I had is to make `LevelVisitor` only have one method `visit(Scene2 scene)` where `interface Scene2 extends Scene` and have specific methods your two special levels will have (they implement `Scene2`, that is if they are supposed to have exactly the same methods, oterhwise my current solution still stand.